# $T(n) = nT(n-1) + 1$ with $T(1)=1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm trying to figure out the order class of this recursion:

\begin{align}
T(n) &= n\cdot T(n-1) + 1 \\
T(1) &= 1
\end{align}

I have to answer it, using the tree method.

I've done a little research and came to idea the solution is $Θ(n!)$.

But from what I've tried to do, I'm stuck with no clue how to continue

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T(n) = 1 + n + n(n-1) + n(n-1)(n-2) + n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + \dots\\
 + n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: yes, and i didn't really understand the result there: 
T(n) = (c - 1) Γ(n + 1) + e Γ(n + 1, 1) (c is an arbitrary parameter)

Comment: it is $$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$ the $Gamma$-function.

Comment: Thank you! didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

You've essentially got $T(n) = n!\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$. It follows that $n! \leqslant T(n) < (e-1) n!$.

Comment: Thank you very much! simple explanation

Answer (score 0):

Argue by induction. I will prove that

> $$n! \le T(n) \le 2 \cdot n!-1$$

Base case $n=1$, it works.

Inductive step, for $n \ge 2$:

$$T(n) = n T(n-1)+1 \ge n((n-1)!)+1 = n! +1 \ge n!$$

and $$T(n) = n T(n-1) +1 \le n (2 \cdot (n-1)! -1) +1 = 2 \cdot n! -n +1 \le 2 \cdot n!-1$$

This concludes the proof that $T(n) = \Theta (n!)$.

Comment: I guess your intention in the end is n! not n? thank you very much!